# Factory reset without erasing data will cause second user data removed?

Tags: factory-reset, multi-user

I have two users accounts in my phone(multiuser/multiple profile)
One is for normal use and other is work profile.

When I want to factory reset my phone from normal user profile(admin user) without erasing internal storage data (only removes apps and their data),will it remove work profile data also?

Both profiles have different passwords.

Will my work profile apps and file downloads, pdfs, documents will still be there? Or else entire work profile will also be deleted?

I'm using oneplus 5.

Comment: Factory reset option without erasing internal storage means all my pics, files, file downloads will be there. But my Google account, downloaded apps from playstore will be deleted. I want to know whether same will happen to my second user profile. Else my work profile will be completely deleted with all data including internal storage associated with it?

Comment: Let me rephrase.. In my phone below is the setting backupandreset->erase all data. Here there is a toggle to delete internal storage, I switched it off so my pics, music will not be deleted. So I'm trying to understand what it would do second user profile in this case. I understand that I shouldn't use the term factory here since it is not erasing everything

Comment: Alright folks. Anyone who has difficulty understanding OP's problem, know that OxygenOS specifically offers a way to factory reset the device while keeping internal storage intact. The user is given the choice to either go for full wipe (including internal storage) or leave the internal storage intact (see this [image](https://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/w830/public/article_images/2020/05/oneplus-reset-2.jpg?itok=bYqY5McZ)). OP is concerned whether keeping internal storage intact would delete or preserve Work profile apps and work profiles storage or not.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: No.. My device is not rooted.

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead tried to factory reset my phone without erasing internal storage.

Device - Oneplus 5, Android 8.1.0 , OOS 5.1.4, Not rooted

Before reset

Users

1. admin
2. work

Below are the storage details

admin       - /mnt/user/0
/storage/emulated/0

work        - /mnt/user/11,
/storage/emulated/11

guest mode  - /mnt/user/10,
/storage/emulated/10

After reset, names of users are reset and only default user name is seen which is Device Owner

Users

1. Device Owner

Below are the storage details

Device Owner  - /mnt/user/0 ,
/storage/emulated/0

Files in */storage/emulated/0* are not deleted. All files of second user got deleted. Looks like it completely wipes second user in this case. Guest user got deleted too.

Comment: thx for the update.. is admin password also reset? afaik it is used for TWRP, would be interesting

Comment: I am using stock recovery and it doesn't ask password after reset. We need to setup new password. I do not know about TWRP recovery.